# Comparison of two files using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm new to PowerShell and trying to compare two files using PowerShell.. and also sending email notification.
Below the code is there..

```
$from = "D:\\Program Files\\ibm\\cognos\\tm1_64\\cmplst.txt" 
$to = "C:\\compare"  
Copy-Item $from $to -Recurse -Force
$From = "xxx@gmail.com"
$To = "xxxx@gmail.com"
$Cc = "xxxx@gmail@gmail"
$Subject = "String Comparison"
$Body = (Compare-Object (Get-Content C:\\compare\\cmplst-1.txt) (Get-Content C:\\compare\\cmplst.txt) -includeequal).InputObject
foreach($line in $comparison)
{
  $Body+= $line
}
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"
Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Cc $Cc -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort -UseSsl -Credential xxx@gmail.com\xxx(password og gmail)
EOH
```

Can anyone please let me know what is the mistake and getting below error...

```
 "Cannot convert 'System.Object[]'
to the
    type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Body'. Specified method is not supported"
```

Comment: It appears to be saying that `Compare-Object` doesn’t return a string, so you can’t say `$Body = (Compare-Object…`. But also, don’t you need to set `$comparison` before you use it?

Comment: @G-Man, I'm new to Power Shell and can you please let me know where can I can use $comparison

Comment: In general, in programming, you can use any variable any time after you set it.  Unfortunately, your script currently uses `$comparison` without setting it.

Comment: @G-Man, Okay Thanks, Will try to do

Answer (score 1):

```
Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Cc $Cc -Subject $Subject -Body ($Body|out-string) -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort -UseSsl -Credential xxx@gmail.com\xxx(password og gmail)
```

That will specifically format the body as a string for the `Send-MailMessage` command

Edit: You might end up finding that you will get an Object type instead of the text.